# Unable to set the permissions of an app through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I've been trying to set the permissions of a native application added through PowerShell with no success.

I'm following the instructions on this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx

I can add the application through PowerShell (step #1), but when I try to set the permissions (step #2) I get several issues.

If I use the Microsoft Active Directory Module PowerShell, I am able to connect but when trying to select a subscription (with the correct values), the result is that the subscription does not exist. Out of curiosity, if I execute the `Get-Subscription` cmdlet I get an empty output. Even if I go ahead and issue the `New-AzureRoleAssignment` cmdlet, I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

If I use the Azure PowerShell, I am not able to issue the Connect-MsolService cmdlet since it says that the cmdlet is not found. Even though, if I go ahead and try the `New-AzureRoleAssignment` cmdlet, I get the same error as above.

Someone knows what am I doing wrong or if I'm missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Azure Powershell Console and use `Import-Module <moduleName>` for the module containing `Connect-MsolService`.

If you are using this combination of modules frequently, I would recommend to put that Import-Module command in the default profile for that console.  I do not know how to do this, but google should.

Comment: Thanks @Xalorous. After lots of attempts using different sources of documentation, I found that issuing `Add-AzureAccount` command at first, basically connects to the Azure account so I could go ahead and execute the rest of cmdlets.